# monotonic vs non monotonic models

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, definition

I am reading [this](https://dl.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=3196909&ftid=1976605&dwn=1&CFID=14770376&CFTOKEN=d0ddd92f0d4abb2b-12014D0D-97F5-7964-B6D362285540D4AC) paper and it mentions monotonic and non monotonic functions. I only only what is monotonic and non monotonic function is, I do not really understand it in the scope of their discussion (ml models).
Anyone can clarify?

> That is, for monotonic
>   models the only thing we need to do is to execute the model for
>   every key and remember the worst over- and under-prediction
>   of a position to calculate the min- and max-error.2 Second, and
>   more importantly, the strong error bounds are not even needed.
>   The data has to be sorted anyway to support range requests,
>   so any error is easily corrected by a local search around the
>   prediction (e.g., using exponential search) and thus, even allows
>   for non-monotonic models.